# React Native navigation header button on the right is not woking

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am developing a mobile application using React Native. I am using React navigation, https://reactnavigation.org/ for the navigation. But I am having a an issue with embedding the button inside the action bar or toolbar or navigation bar or whatever you want to call it. But it is not working.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        headerTitle: "This is the title",
        headerRight: (
                <Button
                onPress={() => {

                }}
                title="+1"
                color="#fff"
                />
            ),
        };
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            active: 'true'
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Content padder>
                    <Tabs>
                    <Tab heading="Shuffles">
                        <Playlists />
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab heading="Public">
                        <Playlists />
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab heading="My Playlists">
                        <Playlists />
                    </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
                    </Content>
                </View>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

As you can see in my code, I am changing the title and adding the button on the right like this.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            headerTitle: "This is the title",
            headerRight: (
                    <Button
                    onPress={() => {

                    }}
                    title="+1"
                    color="#fff"
                    />
                ),
            };
        };
```

But it is only changing the title but not adding the button on the right as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

Why is the button not added on the right?

Comment: Can you try with different color? Maybe it should be about the same color with topbar.

Comment: I tried setting the color to red. But still not showing up the button.

Comment: @WaiYanHein i am facing the same issue . Have you found any solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I hope this will help people facing this issue in react-navigation v4.

On your createBottomTabNavigator (or whatever you use), add this

```js
import { getActiveChildNavigationOptions } from 'react-navigation';

navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        const { index, routes } = navigation.state;
        const { routeName } = routes[index];

        if (routeName === '<Route name>') {
            return {
                ...getActiveChildNavigationOptions(navigation)
            }
        }
```

Now you should be able to customize navigation bar from your component